# Class Not Found Exception on a Servlet

Tags: xml, maven, servlets, jetty

For a project I am trying to implement the [JSCSSMergeServlet](http://code.google.com/p/webutilities/wiki/JSCSSMergeServlet) servlet.

After following the instructions to the letter and starting up Jetty via Maven

I get an error saying:

```
2012-10-22 17:54:14.240:WARN::Failed startup of context \
  org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@7dc64183{/services,\
    C:\workspaceUI\services\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \
    com.googlecode.webutilities.servlets.JSCSSMergeServlet
```

And I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting this.

Did I miss a step?

Is there some other file I need to modify in order to get this up and running?

Comment: You didn't put the jar containing the servlet in your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try including the `webutilities-x.x.x.jar` package in the `web-inf/lib` directory of your web application,  or it can sit elsewhere in your app server/web server `CLASSPATH`

**UPDATE**

The file `webutilities-x.x.x.jar` is not accessible by your applications. [Download](http://code.google.com/p/webutilities/downloads/list) it and use it as told above

Comment: I don't get it, can you explain?